# Encrypt data for Firebase Firestore

Tags: java, android, encryption, google-cloud-firestore

I've an application storing data in a local database. In order to synchronise data between different devices, I want to implement Firebase Firestore.

Though Firebase Firestore's access rules, the admin of the project can still access all data stored in firestore, that's why I want to encrypt the data before uploading... 
The keys for decryption also have to be exchanged with all devices.

How can I realise that? Are there some existing concepts/samples?

Comment: You can create your own encryption/decryption algorithm.

Comment: @Pratik Butani Do you have some examples, concepts, etc. It's my first try to encrypt data & the first time I use a cloud datavase...

Comment: http://www.geero.net/2017/05/how-to-encrypt-a-google-firebase-realtime-database/ check this link out

Comment: You can check [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40175319/1318946)

Comment: @Pratik Butani I need a sample for syncing those keys securely, encryption and decryption is the easiest part of the problem...

Comment: Asking for recommendations for off-site resources is off topic on Stack Overflow. But this seems relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48393557/end-to-end-encryption-with-firestore and probably a few more from these search results: https://www.google.com/search?q=firestore+end+to+end+encryption